# The resource files are not found when creating jar

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a file called `command.xml`, when I work with NetBeans everything works fine.
 But when I create the jar file I have an exception that the file is not found.

Example I have replaced this assignment:

```
String commandPath = "command.xml";
```

with this:

```
String commandPath = getClass().getResources("command.xml").getPath();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: is command.xml inside your jar ?

Comment: yes, is into src folder

Answer (score 0):

I supose that "command.xml" right now is in your project folder (same level where src/ is). To use the resource loading you should move the file in the same folder where the class of the object is that invokes `getClass()`.

Consider you have this class

```
package my.package    
public class Test {

 public Test() {
   String commandPath=getClass().getResources("command.xml").getPath();
 }

}
```

command.xml should be in

```
src/my/package/
```